# How to prove that $5$ unit hypercubes cannot be positioned to cover a unit hypersphere?

Tags: geometry, combinatorial-geometry

How to prove that $5$ unit hypercubes cannot be positioned to cover a unit hypersphere?

The unit hypersphere has hypervolume $\frac{\pi^2}{2} \approx 4.93 \lt 5$ but it seems unlikely that it is possible to waste so little space.  Is there any easy way to see that it is impossible?  How many hypercubes are required, and can their configuration be described in a way that is easy to "visualize"?

Comment: Just to clarify, which dimension are you working in?

Comment: 4 dimensions...

Comment: Well, eight ($8$) axis-aligned hypercubes should suffice, with centers at $\left(0,0,0,\pm\frac{1}{2}\right)$, etc.  What's the answer in three and two dimensions?

Comment: In dimension 2 similarly 4 axis-aligned hypercubes should suffice, with centers at $(0,\pm\frac 12)$, etc. It seems that three cubes does not suffice and we can easily prove this by considering a cover of the four points $(\pm 1,\pm 1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C$ be a unit hypercube, $U=\partial B(0,1)$ be the (hyper-)surface of the unit hypersphere and $\mu$ be the uniform probability measure on $U$. It suffices to show that $\mu(C\cap U)<\frac{1}{5}$ to prove that more than $5$ unit hypercubes are needed to cover the unit hypersphere, i.e., given $(a,b,c,d)\in \mathbb{R}^4\cap B(0,1)$,
$$\int_{\substack{x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=1 \\ (x,y,z,w)\in(a,b,c,d)+C}}1\, d\mu < \frac{1}{5}.$$